# How to understand javascript error debugging message

Tags: javascript

I have used one function in my application which through error message.

This I have done to identify the error line number and file location.

That is fine it work good but I am confused for those line numbers because it has 2 value for each.

Please have look on one of same error message:

```
Error
    at Object.Core.initAlert (http://localhost/demo/core.js:205:22)
    at http://localhost/demo/app.js:26:10
    at _setImmediate (http://localhost/demo/async.js:182:20)
    at http://localhost/demo/async.js:234:13
    at http://localhost/demo/async.js:113:13
    at _arrayEach (http://localhost/demo/async.js:85:13)
    at _forEachOf (http://localhost/demo/async.js:112:9)
    at _each (http://localhost/demo/async.js:77:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (http://localhost/demo/async.js:233:9)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (http://localhost/demo/async.js:210:22)
```

You can see at last of line there are two line numbers and I am confused here that which one is the line number for function statement. First one or second.

For ex. IN first line:

> at Object.Core.initAlert (http://localhost/demo/core.js:**205**:***22***)

205 and 22 are there

Do anyone know about it....

Or is there any other way to track stack of execution in javascript.

Comment: The first one is the line number, the second is the column number

Comment: @depperm thats an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first number is the line number, the second number is the column number.

Answer (score 0):

The first number tells you the line number.

The second number represents the character starting position *in that line* where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

> at Object.Core.initAlert (http://localhost/demo/core.js:205:22)

**205:** is line number and **22:** column number.

Link for more information to understand stack traces.

[Web Inspector - Understanding Stack Traces](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1544/web-inspector-understanding-stack-traces/)

[Chrome Developer Tools Understanding](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/04/chrome-developer-tools-understanding.html)